# Unable to connect to socket.io server running on different port

Tags: socket.io

I am creating a socket.io server on http://localhost:3000.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('success');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am running a very simple web page like this on localhost:5555

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@4.6.0/dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script>
        console.log('yyyyyyyyyyy')
        const chatSocket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is running without any error, but I cant see any connection event on server.

Need some help.